# Python requests & urllib3 Retry - How may retries were made?

Tags: python, python-requests, urllib3

Given following example usage:

```py
adapter = HTTPAdapter(max_retries=Retry(
    total=5,
    backoff_factor=0.1,
    status_forcelist=[429, 500, 502, 503, 504],
    method_whitelist=["HEAD", "GET", "OPTIONS"]
))
session = requests.Session()
session.mount("http://", adapter)
session.mount("https://", adapter)
rsp = session.post(url, json=my_json, params=my_params)
```

How do I tell how many retries were made? I'm trying to debug/diagnose/resolve an issue posted in [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67474679/python-requests-urllib3-retry-how-to-simulate-a-connectionerror-from-inside)

Alternatively, is there a different usage of these libs that provides this?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the list of retries by accessing the `retries.history` property of the underlying `urllib3.response.HTTPResponse` object used by the `requests` library.

In your case, that would be:

```py
rsp.raw.retries.history
```

Comment: If you could show a simple example of how to access the `history`  of retried attempts, then that would be great. Because, if you try to access `raw.retries.history` either it will throw an exception or if the first attempt gets successfully done then it will give you an empty `list`.  With `try/except` it will then skip to the `except` block.

Answer (score -1):

In a worse case (if the first request will get status code in response 429, 500, 502, 503, 504), there will be 5 retries with a backoff factor of 0.1.
You can look there the explanation of each parameter.
https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/urllib3.util.html#module-urllib3.util.retry

Comment: Using wall clock timings to blackbox feels like a pretty rough last-resort. I'd probably sooner implement retries myself.