# Python requests & urllib3 Retry - How to simulate a ConnectionError from inside the internal retry loop?

Tags: python, python-requests, urllib3

Given following example usage:

```py
adapter = HTTPAdapter(max_retries=Retry(
    total=5,
    backoff_factor=0.1,
    status_forcelist=[429, 500, 502, 503, 504],
    method_whitelist=["HEAD", "GET", "OPTIONS"]
))
session = requests.Session()
session.mount("http://", adapter)
session.mount("https://", adapter)
rsp = session.post(url, json=my_json, params=my_params)
```

I occasionally get:

```
('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))
```

I would like to establish retries around this as well ([related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67474641/python-requests-urllib3-retry-how-may-retries-were-made)), and I'd like to be able to test it by issuing such an error from inside the library's retry loop.

How do I do that?

Comment: Wow, so these kind of errors are, by default, not handled by Retry? Good to know! Also, it would be great to know if you solved this?

Comment: would something like `raise http.client.RemoteDisconnected("Remote server disconnected")` work?